# How Can I Dynamically Create Table Rows From A List Of Records?

Tags: elm

My **Model** type is:

```
type alias Model =
    {   freeSyllables : List FreeSyllable
    ,   freeSyllableInput : String
    ,   usageStartInput : Bool
    ,   usageMidInput : Bool
    ,   usageEndInput : Bool
    }
```

The **FreeSyllable** type looks like:

```
type alias FreeSyllable =
    {   syllable : String
    ,   usage : Usage
    }
```

The **Usage** type has three Boolean fields:

```
type alias Usage =
    {   start : Bool
    ,   mid : Bool
    ,   end : Bool
    }
```

I tried to render each item of the model's FreeSyllables-List to a table.

I didn't succeed.

So my question is how I can dynamically render each of the model's "FreeSyllables" into a proper html table with these columns:

- syllable (textbox)
- start usage (checkbox)
- mid usage (checkbox)
- end usage (checkbox)
- actions (save-Button)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'll have to attach event handlers (that fire Msg), but here is example view:

```
view : Model -> Html Msg
view model =
    table [] <|
        [ tr []
            [ th [] [ text "syllable" ]
            , th [] [ text "start" ]
            , th [] [ text "mid" ]
            , th [] [ text "end" ]
            , th [] [ text "actions" ]
            ]
        ]
            ++ (List.map viewItem model.freeSyllables)


viewItem : FreeSyllable -> Html Msg
viewItem s =
    tr []
        [ th [] [ text s.syllable ]
        , th [] [ input [ type_ "checkbox", checked s.usage.start ] [] ]
        , th [] [ input [ type_ "checkbox", checked s.usage.mid ] [] ]
        , th [] [ input [ type_ "checkbox", checked s.usage.end ] [] ]
        , th [] [ button [] [ text "save" ] ]
        ]
```